# Why is the LibreOffice Save As dialog full screen and immovable in Windows?

Tags: windows, libreoffice, save-as, dialog

When saving a document in LibreOffice, the Save As dialog covers all that is below it, cannot be resized and cannot be moved, quite annoying if the title you want is now hidden by the dialog. Is there a good reason for it? Can it be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The Save As Window is just maximized, double click the title bar to and it should tile and become "moveable".

Comment: Not sure how I didn't figure that out myself..! Sometimes the simple things just need help. Now it's even remembered the configuration and keeps doing it..! Cheers.

Comment: **Please stop self-vandalism.**